# Getting "Invariant Violation" error with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: apollo

I'm using Apollo GraphQL but I'm new to it and I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "framesToPop": 1,
    "name": "Invariant Violation"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: "https://api.example.com/v3/ListingsQuery",
    fetch
});
const automaticPersistedQueryLink = createPersistedQueryLink();
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([automaticPersistedQueryLink, httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
const variables = {
    filters: {statuses: ["ACTIVE", "UNLISTED"]},
    orderBys: [{sortField: "STATUS", sortOrder: "DESC"}],
    shouldFetchHostMultiListingAgendaPermissions: true,
    offset: 0,
    shouldFetchListingPermissions: false,
    count: 15,
    query: null
};
await apolloClient.query({
    query: {},
    variables
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No number after the "Invariant Violation" message? Not sure about this (I'm relatively new to Apollo myself), but I think that since Apollo Client 3.1.0, there should always be a number after Invariant Violation messages. Is it possible that you are using an older release of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it appears that Apollo is being started in "production mode" rather than "developpement mode". By starting it in development mode, Apollo would provide you more detailed error messages. To fix this, start your node process with `env.NODE_ENV` set to `development`. Sorry if this is not clear, but I can't be more precise here, as the exact procedure depends on how your application is being started and/or which framework you are using...

Still, in recent versions, you should have a numeric error code in the error message when run in production mode, such as `Invariant Violation: 42`. These numeric error codes makes it easier to diagnose problems, even in production mode. Make sure you are using a recent version of @apollo/client (latest is 3.2.5 at the time I'm writing this; see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/client).

Now, regarding the error itself... The full error message is most likely `Invariant Violation: You must wrap the query string in a "gql" tag.` It is due to the fact that you are providing an empty query, as shown below:

```
await apolloClient.query({
    query: {},   // <--- Empty query here
    variables
});
```

There are several ways to provide queries to the Apollo client. The simplest way to do so is to embed your GraphQL query in the JavaScript source code, using the "gql tag" notation, such as this:

```
await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      query TestQuery {
        launch(id: 56) {
          id
          mission {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables
});
```

This should work out of the box, but for performance reason, you should add a GraphQL compilation step in your build process. Maybe this process is already in place (for example, if you are started your project using a framework such as Create React Apps or Gatsby...). See this document for explanations on this (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/babel/).